# Middleware in laravel does not works properly

Tags: laravel-5.1

I am trying to apply middleware on my routes like this:

```
Route::get('twitterlogin','TwitterController@gettwitterlogin'); 
Route::post('twitterlogin','TwitterController@posttwitterlogin');   
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'],function()
{
    Route::get('twitternewsfeed','TwitterController@gettwitternewsfeed');   
    Route::post('postimage','TwitterController@postimage');     
    Route::post('posttweet','TwitterController@posttweet');     
    Route::get('twitterlogout','TwitterController@gettwitterlogout');   
    Route::post('editprofilepic','TwitterController@posteditprofilepic');   
    Route::post('searchuser','TwitterController@postsearchuser');   
    Route::post('edittweet{id}','TwitterController@postedittweet');     
    Route::get('deletetweet{id}','TwitterController@getdeletetweet');   
    Route::post('editprofile','TwitterController@posteditprofile');     
    Route::get('userprofile{email}','TwitterController@getuserprofile');  
});
```

And when i am trying to submit my login form it does not bring me on next page. It again opens the login page....what is the exact problem in this? My authenticate middleware is as follows....

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

/**
 * Create a new middleware instance.
 *
 * @param  Guard  $auth
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Guard $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
}

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('twitterlogin');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using the `Route::post('twitterlogin','TwitterController@posttwitterlogin')` route to perform your login operation - please ensure that you're logging the user in with [Laravel's Auth](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#authentication-quickstart) correctly and redirecting the user to the appropriate route in the `posttwitterlogin` method

I feel you also may also be using a different table to store user data - in which case, kindly ensure that you have your [auth.php config file setup appropriately](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/using-different-table-for-authentication-in-laravel)

In case you're using a custom authentication mechanism for some reason, you'll need to replace `$this->auth->guest()` in your middleware with the appropriate alternative check for the user not being logged-in

For eg: if you're setting a Session variable called `is_authenticated` to `true` with `\Session::put('is_authenticated', true)` upon successfully logging in, you'll check for it with `if(\Session::get('is_authenticated') === true)` in your Middleware instead of relying on the Laravel Auth method `if ($this->auth->guest())`